# How to convert time to T Z format in python

Tags: python, python-datetime

I would like to convert today's date to below format in python

What I tried:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d_date = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> reg_format_date = d_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")
>>> print(reg_format_date)
2020-08-04 06:40:52 PM
```

Expected format:

```
2017-10-18T04:46:53.553472514Z
```

can some one suggest please

Comment: It appears you're looking for UTC time since your timezone is `Z`, correct?

Comment: Hi @Mark Ransom actually i am using  one api call which wants time stamp from in this format only.. this was notes regarding thatThe $filter argument is very restricted and allows only the following patterns.
- List events for a resource group: $filter=eventTimestamp ge '2014-07-16T04:36:37.6407898Z' and eventTimestamp le '2014-07-20T04:36:37.6407898Z' and resourceGroupName eq 'resourceGroupName'. so wanted to covert current time to this format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to get the current UTC time and convert to the ISO-8601 format (which is what your example shows).  The timezone is hardcoded to `Z`.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat() + 'Z'
```

Comment: its working thanks

Answer (score 6):

- Use `utcnow()` instead of `now()` to get the UTC time.
- Use the `isoformat()` method. You'll need to add the trailing `"Z"` yourself.

In summary:

```
from datetime import datetime
reg_format_date = datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + "Z"
```

Comment: this is too working